# Why is the name of archive files not displayed in red color

Tags: 20.04, fish

I use the command of "ls" to list all files in a directory. However, I found that the name of archive files such as ".tar.gz" is not displayed in red color.The version of the Ubuntu is 20.04. Can someone help me?

By the way, the shell I used is the fish shell.

Comment: Do other filetypes have the expected colors? Are you using the bash shell, or some other? Do you have a `~/.dircolors` file? Have you examined the values in the `LS_COLORS` variable? Please use the [edit] button to add more details to your question.

Comment: @steeldriver Hi, thanks for the comment. The shell I used is fish shell. Other filetypes such as executable files have the expected green color. I do not have a ~/.dircolors file. And I enter the command of "echo $LS_COLORS" on the terminal and did not see any information.

Comment: Thanks - I have added the [fish tag](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/fish) since this is important information (the fish shell defines its own `ls` function)

Answer (score 2):

The GNU coreutils implementation of `ls` has *some* built in colors, but the red coloring of archive files such as `.tar`, `.tar.gz`, `.tar.bz2`, `.tgz` that you may be familiar with from using the Ubuntu bash shell relies on values set via the `LS_COLORS` environment variable. From your description, it sounds like you are seeing only the built in colors.

In bash, `ls` is *aliased* to `ls --color=auto` in the default `~/.bashrc` file (copied from the `/etc/skel` directory on account creation), and `LS_COLORS` is set in the same file by `eval`ing the output of the `dircolors -b` command - optionally using a custom `~/dircolors` file if it exits.

In the fish shell the situation is slightly different. If you installed fish via apt from the Ubuntu repository, then you should find that `ls` is defined as a *shell function*, imported from the `/usr/share/fish/functions/ls.fish` file (which is provided by the `fish-common` dependent package). You can view this function using the builtin `functions` command:

```
functions ls
```

You should see that the function calls a further function, `__fish_set_lscolors` which performs the equivalent of the .bashrc `eval dircolors -b` (although it uses csh-compatible `dircolors -c`). This function first checks whether `LS_COLORS` has already been set, and only applies the `dircolors` if it has not.

So, the possible reasons that you are seeing only the built in ls colors are:

1. you installed and/or configured fish some other way, so that the default `ls` shell function is not loaded
2. the `ls` function is loaded, but doesn't call the default `__fish_set_lscolors`
3. you are invoking `fish` from an environment that exports an `LS_COLORS` variable which does not define the red color for archive files (for example, is empty).